# Como carregar o Flaskbb com o Nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

Eu segui a documentação e instalei tudo sem problemas, mas o Nginx só mostra a página padrão dele avisando que está rodando.

O fórum flaskbb nunca carrega.

Eu tentei remover o import do arquivo de configuração default do Nginx e importar somente o arquivo de configuração flaskbb mas isso resultou em um erro 502 - *bad request*.

Alguém tem uma pista de como carregar o fórum?

Aqui estão os três arquivos de configuração:

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
 worker_connections 768;
 # multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
#include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flaskbb; <-- this is commented becouse dont work
}

#mail {
#    # See sample authentication script at:
#    # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#    # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#    # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#    # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#    server {
#        listen     localhost:110;
#        protocol   pop3;
#        proxy      on;
#    }
# 
#    server {
#        listen     localhost:143;
#        protocol   imap;
#        proxy      on;
#    }
#}
```

flaskbb (arquivo de configuração do nginx em /sites-avaleable/flaskbb)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.forums.flaskbb.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.forums.flaskbb.log;

  location / {
      try_files $uri @flaskbb;
  }

  # Static files
  location /static {
     alias /home/andre/py/rv/flaskbb/flaskbb/static/;
  }

  location ~ ^/_themes/([^/]+)/(.*)$ {
      alias /home/andre/py/rv/flaskbb/themes/$1/static/$2;
  }

  # robots.txt
  location /robots.txt {
      alias /home/andre/py/rv/flaskbb/flaskbb/static/robots.txt;
  }

  location @flaskbb {
      uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:30002;
      include uwsgi_params;
  }
}
```

flaskbb.ini (arquivo do uwsgi em /apps-available/flaskbb.ini)

```
[uwsgi]
base = /home/andre/py/rv/flaskbb
home = /home/andre/.virtualenvs/rv/
pythonpath = %(base)
socket = 127.0.0.1:30002
module = wsgi
callable = flaskbb
uid = apps
gid = apps
logto = /home/andre/py/flaskbb/logs/uwsgi.log
plugins = python
```

Comment: I think that you failed to notice that esta comunidade está em português, so I'll ask you to traduzir a sua pergunta para o português. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I dont see that...

Comment: Você chegou a executar `nginx_ensite` para ativar o seu site no Nginx? Ou seja, a configuração do seu site aparece em `ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` ?